# JavaScript parseInt Conversion

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a calculation that populates a text box based on an onblur event. For some reason, my result is showing a NaN. I am not used to JS so any help will be appreciated.

NOTE: I am most actively working on the last function - markupNumCheck() because once this function is working I can simply just apply it to the other two functions.

Here is the JS:

```
function unitToSales(){
    var unitPrice = document.getElementById("inputCost");
    var percentMarkup = document.getElementById("inputMarkup");
    var salesPrice = document.getElementById("inputPrice");

    parseInt(unitPrice.value);
    parseInt(percentMarkup.value);
    parseInt(salesPrice.value);

    if(unitPrice.value != "" && percentMarkup.value != "" ){
         salesPrice.value = (unitPrice * (1+percentMarkup));
     }

}

function salesToUnit(){

    var unitPrice = document.getElementById("inputCost");
    var percentMarkup = document.getElementById("inputMarkup");
    var salesPrice = document.getElementById("inputPrice");

    parseInt(unitPrice.value);
    parseInt(percentMarkup.value);
    parseInt(salesPrice.value);

    if(percentMarkup.value != "" && salesPrice.value != "" ){
         unitPrice.value = parseInt(unitPrice * (1+percentMarkup));
     }
}

function markupNumCheck(){
    var unitPrice = document.getElementById("inputCost");
    var percentMarkup = document.getElementById("inputMarkup");
    var salesPrice = document.getElementById("inputPrice");

    parseInt(unitPrice.value);
    parseInt(percentMarkup.value);
    parseInt(salesPrice.value);

    if(unitPrice.value != "" && percentMarkup.value != "" ){
         salesPrice.value = (unitPrice * (1+percentMarkup));
    } else if (percentMarkup.value != "" && salesPrice.value != "" ){
         unitPrice.value = (unitPrice * (1+percentMarkup));
    }
}
```

And here is HTML where I call code:
NOTE: This obviously is a form, I did not copy the entire document because the rest is irrelevant.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCost">Unit Cost</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCost" name="inputCost" onblur="unitToSales()" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMarkup">Percent Markup</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMarkup" name="inputMarkup" onblur="markupNumCheck()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCost">Sales Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice" onblur="salesToUnit()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputQuantity">Quantity</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputQuantity" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all again for any help that you may be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` will return the parsed integer value. When you call `parseInt(value)` and don't assign the value to a variable, the parsed value is just discarded. You are using the variable `unitPrice` after as a number, but it actually holds a DOM element, that is why you get the `NaN`.

You can fix it by inlining the `parseInt` call in your expression:

```
salesPrice.value = (parseInt(unitPrice.value) * (1+parseInt(percentMarkup)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign each of your variables to the `parseInt` result.

So for example you'd reuse the `unitPrice` variable and assign it to the `parseInt` result

`var unitPrice = document.getElementById("inputCost");`

`unitPrice = parseInt(unitPrice);`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that every time you tried to use `parseInt` that you don't save the result like so:

```
var resultInt = parseInt(SomeString);
```

So when you try to calculate your values together you get `NaN` because they still in string form.

If you look at this **if-statement** for example in **salesToUnit()**:

```
if(percentMarkup.value != "" && salesPrice.value != "" ){
     unitPrice.value = parseInt(unitPrice * (1+percentMarkup));
 }
```

`unitPrice` and `percentMarkup` are not parsed as integers so you are adding `1` (an integer) to `percentMarkup` (a string) and then multiplying it to `unitPrice`(also a string) and **THEN** parsing the result giving you `NaN` and setting that to `unitPrice.value`.

I would like to add that the `parseInt` calls that happen in the beginning of **salesToUnit()** when would seem unnecessary since if theres no value in `percentMarkup` and `SalesPrice` and would be better let till once you do you check. I would flip it around like this and change **salesToUnit()** to something like this:

```
if(percentMarkup.value != "" && salesPrice.value != "" )
{
     var salesPriceInt = parseInt(salesPrice.value);
     var percentMarkupInt = parseInt(percentMarkup.value);

     unitPrice.value = unitPriceInt * (1+percentMarkupInt);
}
```

Also incorporating the `safeParseInt` function mentioned by **@Vitalii** would help as well to be even safer!

I hope you find this useful!